# PHP - How to change the value of a local php.ini directive

Tags: php, ini

I am trying to set the value of the php.ini `error_reporting` property to `E_ALL`, however, I am only able to change the master value, while the local value remains the same.
Note that in my case, this property must be set through the ini file, not programmatically using PHP.

What I have come up with so far:

- There is no directive in the .htaccess file that could be causing this.
- The value of the ini property `Additional .ini files parsed` is `(none)`
- The `Loaded Configuration File` has the property `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL` as it should.

The operating system is OS X 10.10.2

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party code which is calling `error_reporting()` at runtime?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowsk I have WordPress installed. Is there a way to track down something like that?